Has there been research on definability predicates, just like there has been research on truth predicates?
I know that there has been research on truth predicates, namely, formal theories of arithmetic with a truth predicate. You basically add a predicate $T$ to the language that models truth. I wonder, has there ever been research on definability predicates? Basically, it is a formal theory that adds a predicate $D$, for definability. I would love to see some references, if there are any.

A couple of my old MO questions might be related: 1 (which was very naive in retrospect) and 2.

Also, note that if $M\models\mathsf{PA}$ then the set of definable elements of $M$ is definable in $M$ iff every element of $M$ is definable in $M$. This is because otherwise we can (using the full induction provided by $\mathsf{PA}$) consider "the smallest undefinable element." On the other hand, every completion of $\mathsf{PA}$ has exactly one (up to isomorphism) such "pointwise-definable" model, so this isn't as stringent as it may appear. (Related.)

The first (and close-to-only) paper I'm aware of on the subject is Tarski, A problem concerning the notion of definability. Its opening line is relevant to the question at hand:

We are inclined to believe that, by means of an argument entirely analogous
to that which leads to the Richard antinomy, the notion of definability as applied to entities discussed in a formal system can easily be shown not to be itself definable in this system. It will be seen from this discussion that actually the situation is not quite so simple as it would appear at first glance.

Certainly there are "rich" structures over which the definability predicate is easily definable. Many theories, such as $\mathsf{PA}$ and (less trivially) $\mathsf{ZFC}$, even admit models in which the definability predicate can be just $x=x$. So unlike the truth predicate (or its nonstandard analogues), there need be no "interesting" structure theory for arbitrary models of reasonable theories.
For this reason I think that there hasn't really been any impetus to explicitly refer to a "definability predicate" as such. Instead, results are phrased in terms of definability on its own, so e.g. "There is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in which every set is definable" instead of "There is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ whose definability predicate is given by $x=x$."
